# How to access properties from $.get JSON file?

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm trying to load data which I stored in a json in the folder "data" and a file called "data.json" but everytime I get the response "undefined" instead of the answer to "text" in "data.json".

```
function load_data() {
    var variable = "text";
    $.get("data/data.json", function(data, status, xhr) {
        if (status == "success") {
            if (data[variable] === variable) {
                altert(data);
            } else {
                alert("most likely undefined");
                return 0;
            }
        };
        if (status == "error") {
            alert("load error");
        };
    });
}
```

Comment: why not use fetch??

Comment: Is the file actually a valid JSON? It would be if it contains "text" with double quotes. However, if the text does not include double quotes, it is invalid JSON.

Comment: The json is completely valid. I checked with https://jsonlint.com/.

Comment: Could you share the json file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should `JSON.parse` the result from the JSON file, this way you can access properties on the object. At the moment you're trying to access `String["text"]`.

```
function load_data() {
    var variable = "text";
    $.get("data/data.json", function (data, status, xhr) {
        const parsed = JSON.parse(data);

        if (status == "success") {
            if (parsed[variable] === variable) {
                altert(parsed)
            }
            else {
                alert("most likely undefined");
                return 0;
            };
        };
        if (status == "error") {
            alert("load error");
        };
    });
}
```